# Trying to get Vundle to work with VIM

Tags: vim, git

I am following [this](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim) tutorial, which is actually the **Vundle**'s homepage in *github* and in `step 3` it's telling me to put some code into `.vimrc`:

"*Put this at the top of your .vimrc to use Vundle. Remove plugins you don't need, they are for illustration purposes.*"

However, I don't have `.vimrc` file and from the research I have done people said it shouldn't be necessarily there to start with. So I created this file in `/usr/share/vim` and put the code it needed in it.

In this level I might be doing something wrong cuz I can't proceed to `level 4` and run the `:PluginInstall` inside *vim*.

I would like to know where did I do the wrong step.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to fix this problem asking a friend who uses Vundle already.

All I did was to move the `.vimrc` file that I have prepared to my home directory then it'll be

```
~/.vimrc
```

and Now it's all working.